# Why do I get a floating point exception?

Tags: c

While trying to take some arguments for C. I found it really difficult to get `argv[]` to work. I have:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  void updateNext();
  void fcfs();
  void spn();
  void srt();

  fp = fopen(argv[0],"r");
  op = fopen("output.dat","a+");

  if (strcmp(argv[1],"FCFS")!=0)
  {
    fcfs();
  }

  if (strcmp(argv[1],"SPN")!=0)
  {
    spn();
  }

  if (strcmp(argv[1],"SRT")!=0)
  {
    srt();
  }
}
```

I would like to enter something in a format of `myprog input.data FCFS`, but the above code gives me an error for "float point exception" the exception is gone after I hard code `input.dat` as a string in the program. Something wrong with `argv[0]` perhaps?

Comment: "Any wrong with argv[0] perhaps?"  Yes.  argv[0] typically refers to the compiled binary myprog, and never contains the first command-line parameter.

Comment: `strcmp(argv[1],"FCFS")!=0` - according to the rest of your code should be `strcmp(argv[1],"FCFS")==0`. Since `strcmp` returns 0 if strings match

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C, `argv[0]` is the *name of your program* (or more precisely, the first word the user typed on the command line to run your program, if run from a shell).

So, avoiding `argv[0]` for your purposes, you'll want to look at `argv[1]` for the file name and `argv[2]` for the other parameter.

This would have been clear if you had used a debugger to trace through your program, or simply printed the value before you used it:

```
printf("using file name %s\n", argv[0]);
fp = fopen(argv[0],"r");
```

It's also a good idea to check that you have sufficient command line parameters by validating `argc` before accessing `argv`:

```
if (argc < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "not enough command line parameters\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In C `argv[0]` is typically the name with which the program was called. You're looking for  `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`.

As side notes:

- you should be checking `argc` before touching `argv`
- **there's no guarantee `argv[0]` contains the name of the program** or even something sensible